# Search for ^@ in register '+'

Tags: register, mode, visual

After yanking into register `+` from Visual Block mode, the lines break are marked with `^@`.

I would like to detect this character, but I can't..
For example, if register `+` contains `^@` as shown below

[image]

```
stridx(getreg('+'), '^@')
```

returns -1. Same for

```
stridx(getreg('+'), '\^\@')
```

So what is the proper way of detecting it, more generally, inside a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^@` is the code for the NUL character. It is used by Vim to separate the lines internally.

The clipboard contains actually new lines that are output in your context using the NUL character.

You can input the new line character using the following key sequence <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl j</kbd>

In VimScript the new line character is `"\n"`.

The following code should not return -1

```
stridx(getreg('+'), "\n")
```

Comment: you mean `Ctrl-V` `Ctrl-J`?

Comment: @Christian, thanks for the hint :-)

Comment: Character `^@` is actually called NUL, not really "null" (see [`man ascii`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html)) and is actually represented by `\0`. The `\n` escape is actually "new line" (ascii LF or `nr2char(10)`). The reason why `^@` is showing for new lines here is explained in [`:help NL-used-for-Nul`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#NL-used-for-Nul), Vim uses `"\n"` to represent NUL bytes internally and this representation leaks sometimes, resulting in the display including `^@` for new lines.

Comment: @filbranden, thanks for the precision. I adapted the answer accordingly. Let me know if it needs further improvement.